# How to migrate app to EU datacenter?

Tags: google-app-engine

Our app has been invited to the early testers program for the EU datacenter option, but it's not clear how to migrate our app there.

The invitation included a link to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading, which seems to imply that I need to choose the EU datacenter when creating an new app, but when I try to do so, I don't see "Location Options" on the subsequent page.

How do I migrate?